# array<> can’t simply swap pointers internally

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, complexity-theory, swap

For the container array<> introduced to STL with TR1, I have a problem below.

In Page 263 of book "The C++ standard library A Tutorial and Reference":

> Note, however, that an array<> can’t simply swap pointers internally. For this reason, swap() has linear complexity and the effect that iterators and references don’t swap containers with their elements.

I wondered why array<> cannot considering its constant overhead for swapping pointers?

Comment: Probably because it's not implemented with pointers.

Comment: It is designed to be a zero-overhead drop-in replacement for C-style arrays. So it holds the data directly. There is no pointer to data stored elsewhere, so data cannot be swapped with a simple pointer swap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

std::array is a template class that encapsulate a `stati`c array, stored inside the object itself, which means that, if you instantiate the class on the stack, the static array will be on the stack. **Its size has to be known at compile time.** Thus it can't be implemented with pointers (i.e., dynamic memory which has to be allocated in runtime).

Thus, a possible implementation for `std::array` would be:

```
template<class _Ty, size_t _Size>
class array {
  //...
  _Ty _Elems[_Size == 0 ? 1 : _Size];
};
```

As you can see there are no pointers involved but rather concrete arrays.

**You can't swap concrete arrays.** Thus, it takes linear time to swap element by element the contents of one array with the elements of the other.

Comment: There are no pointers in your "possible" implementation. This does not explain why there cannot be a possible implementation with pointers.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanx, addressed that.

Comment: That's better. Swapped -1 for +1.

Answer (score 11):

You're probably falling for the fallacy of "C[++] arrays are just pointers." **No, they are not.** In some contexts (mostly function calls), arrays *decay* to pointers. More formally, an implicit conversion exists from an array to a pointer to its first member.

But they are entirely different things. A pointer is an address - typically 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the HW. An array is a sequence of objects one after the other. `sizeof` can tell the difference:

```
int main()
{
  int arr[5];
  int *p = arr;  // decay/implicit conversion happening here
  std::cout << sizeof arr << ':' << sizeof p;
}
```

This will output `20:4` on a typical 32-bit PC.

So as you can see, swapping pointers is fast, but swapping real arrays is not - you really have to swap individual elements, so that takes time linear in the number of elements. *And note that `std::array` is indeed a wrapper around an array.*

---

The confusion is made worse by an ufortunate C and C++ syntax decision - on function parameter types, array syntax can be used, but the "decay" is performed on the type itself. Which means that functions like this:

```
void foo(int a[]);
void bar(char b[40]);
```

do not actually take arrays, they take pointers. These function declarations are *exactly the same* as these:

```
void foo(int *a);
void bar(char *b);
```

So much so that you can actually use one as a forward declaration for the other:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int a[40]);

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    foo(&x);
}

void foo(int *a)
{
    std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/j4ymTj)